# In Plone, if the hard disk is full, wish to add another hard disk. How to give upload path?

Tags: python, linux, plone

I had plone installed in 1 server. Now the hard disk space is full. I wish to add another hard disk to it. In Plone GUI, how to specify the path for the new files to be up loaded in the Zope server? i.e extended hard disk space. I have installed Plone 4.1.4 on linux running on python 2.7

Comment: I never used the Plone GUI. I would be surprised if it lets you specify the storage directory path without editing config files. Further, do you realise that you will need to move previous data, iow that Plone will not let you "just" add a second disk to extend storage ?

Comment: First check if your Linux is using LVM – LVM is an abstraction layer that roughly speaking lets you add space to existing partitions by adding new physical drives.